# ERROR : Could not execute build using Gradle distribution

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx

The full error message is

```
Configured compileSdkVersion is invalid: 21 (C:/Users/Zachry/AppData/Local/Android/android-sdk/platforms/android-21
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip'.
```

I followed Almas B's tutorial on using JavaFX in eclipse to develop android applications, link is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbQqnTnqaKk

I'm pretty sure I did everything right, but when I try to execute the 'android' task on gradle it gives me that error.

Does anyone have any fixes? Much appreciated.

Comment: can you run just the gradle app, no tasks? gradlew.bat in command line on windows or ./gradlew in linux & mac in terminal

Comment: have you installed the android-21 ?

Comment: @FunkTheMonk I tried to run typing "gradlew" in the command line and it says its unrecognized, would I need to set a system environment variable for it? If so, what would I even put?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @L. Swifter for making me recheck this, it turns out I had installed android 23, not 21. For anyone having the same problem I did, make 100% sure you're using Android API 21 in your SDK Manager.

Comment: Alternatively you could have explicitly set the sdk version the plugin should use with the compileSdkVersion setting inside the android configuration (http://docs.gluonhq.com/javafxports/#_android_4): jfxmobile { android { compileSdkVersion = '23' } }